# How to substitude some characters with an space between them in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to substitute some characters by some strings, but when I try this happens:

```r
Group <- "ABC"
A <- "0.25 0.65 0.48"
B <- "0.054 0.41 0.09"
C <- "0.8 0.047 0.34"
Group <- gsub("A", A, Group)
Group <- gsub("B", B, Group)
Group <- gsub("C", C, Group)
Group
```

When I group them there is no space between A, B and C. The above code results in:

```
0.25 0.65 0.480.054 0.41 0.090.8 0.047 0.34
```

I want that the input be like this:

```
0.25 0.65 0.48 0.054 0.41 0.09 0.8 0.047 0.34
```

I will appreciate if you can help me with this.

Comment: That is not correct R syntax in A, B and C, you are either missing some commas or string delimeters.

Comment: Your script, as is, will not run without error.  Please show us the actual script you are running.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I just change the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform `Group` a bit, i.e., `trimsw(gsub(""," ",Group))`, then `" "` is inserted among characters in `Group`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several syntactical errors, but let me present you what I think you are trying to accomplish:

```
Group <- 'ABC'
A <- paste(0.25, 0.65, 0.48)
Group = gsub('A', A, Group)
[1] "0.25 0.65 0.48BC"
```

EDIT: Seeing your reformatted question, I would say the only change is to put a space between your Group letters:

```
Group <- 'A B C'
```

Or paste an empty character at the end of all groups of numbers:

```
A <- paste(0.25, 0.65, 0.48, "")
```

Comment: Thanks, I put spaces between the group letters

Answer (score 0):

just use paste with `collapse = ""`:

```
A <- "0.25 0.65 0.48"
B <- "0.054 0.41 0.09"
C <- "0.8 0.047 0.34"

paste(A, B, C, collaspe = "")
"0.25 0.65 0.48 0.054 0.41 0.09 0.8 0.047 0.34 "
```